# rails - insert data to rows using spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, spreadsheet

I want to "run" iterative on my db, and insert the data into the rows.
But, I keep getting the same error again and again

> "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Spreadsheet::Row into Integer"

My code look like that:

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
sheet1.row(0).push "Time", "Name", "Phone", "Email"
[0,1,2,3].each{|col| sheet1.column(col).width = 19}
sheet1.each do |row|
  object.each do |o|
    sheet1.(row).push o.time, o.name, o.phone, o.email
  end
end

book.write '../excel.xls'
```

Thank you ahead guys!!!

Comment: did you mean to put sheet1.row[0].push "Time", "Name", "Phone", "Email"  rather than sheet1.row(0).push "Time", "Name", "Phone", "Email"

Comment: no... my problem, is with the data, at the second loop :
sheet1.each do |row|
object.each do |o|

Comment: Oh ok I see now.  What is sheet1?  Is that an array and if so an array of what?

Comment: `sheet1.(row)` this syntax is setting off all sorts of alarm bells.

Comment: @shadwell  what you mean ?

Comment: @ruby_newbie well sheet1 is my excel sheet that I'm working on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `row` here `sheet1.(row).` to a method that's expecting an integer.

#### Update

Btw, I think this is the code you want:

```
object.each_with_index do |o, i|
  sheet1.insert_row i+1, [ o.time, o.name, o.phone, o.email ]
end
```

Comment: well, i've change a little bit my code, but it's still not work good  :
 row = 1
    while row <= 14
      object.each do |o|
        sheet1.row(row).push o.time, o.name, o.phone, o.email, 
      end
      row = row + 1
    end

its not concatenate the data for the rows correctly